# Bad output with python html parsing

Tags: python

I have an html file in C:\temp.
I want to extract this text

```
Death - Individual Thought Patterns (1993), Progressive Death Metal
http://xxxxxxx.bb/1196198
http://yyyyyyyyyyyy.com/files/153576607/d-xxx_xxx_xxx-xxxxx-xxxxx.rar
Alfadog (1994), Black Metal
```

from this block of code

```
<td width='99%' style='word-wrap:break-word;'><div><img src='style_images/1/nav_m.gif' border='0'  alt='&gt;' width='8' height='8' />&nbsp;<b>Death - Individual Thought Patterns (1993)</b>, Progressive Death Metal</div></td>
<!--HideBegin--><div class='hidetop'>Hidden text</div><div class='hidemain'><!--HideEBegin--><!--coloro:#FF0000--><span style="color:#FF0000"><!--/coloro--><b>Download:</b><!--colorc--></span><!--/colorc--><br />Download from <a href="http://xxxxxxx.bb/1196198" target="_blank">ifolder.ru <i>*Death - Individual Thought Patterns (1993)* <b>by Dissident God</b></i></a><br /><!--HideEnd--></div><!--HideEEnd--><br /><!--HideBegin--><div class='hidetop'>Hidden text</div><div class='hidemain'><!--HideEBegin--><!--coloro:#ff0000--><span style="color:#ff0000"><!--/coloro--><b>Download (mp3@VBR230kbps) (67 MB):</b><!--colorc--></span><!--/colorc--><br />Download from <a href="http://yyyyyyyyyyyy.com/files/153576607/d-xxx_xxx_xxx-xxxxx-xxxxx.rar" target="_blank">rapidshare.com <i>*Death - Individual Thought Patterns (Remastered) (2008)* <b>by smashter</b></i></a><!--HideEnd--></div><!--HideEEnd-->
<td width='99%' style='word-wrap:break-word;'><div><img src='style_images/1/nav_m.gif' border='0'  alt='&gt;' width='8' height='8' />&nbsp;<b>Alfadog (1994)</b>, Black Metal</div></td>
```

The extracted text must be saved in a file called links.txt

Despite my changes my script only ever extracts this text to me

```
http://xxxxxxx.bb/1196198
http://yyyyyyyyyyyy.com/files/153576607/d-xxx_xxx_xxx-xxxxx-xxxxx.rar
```

But I want you to extract this text and like this

```
Death - Individual Thought Patterns (1993), Progressive Death Metal
http://xxxxxxx.bb/1196198
http://yyyyyyyyyyyy.com/files/153576607/d-xxx_xxx_xxx-xxxxx-xxxxx.rar
Alfadog (1994), Black Metal
```

This is the script

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Open the HTML file in read mode
with open("C:/temp/pagina.html", "r") as f:
    html = f.read()

# Create a Beautiful Soup object from HTML code
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Initialize a list to contain the extracted text
extracted_text = []

# Find all td's with style "word-wrap:break-word"
tds = soup.find_all("td", style="word-wrap:break-word")

# For each td found, look for the div tag and the b tag inside
# and extract the text contained in these tags
for td in tds:
    div_tag = td.find("div")
    b_tag = div_tag.find("b")
    if b_tag:
        text = b_tag.text
        # Also add the text after the b tag
        text += td.text[td.text.index(b_tag.text) + len(b_tag.text):]
        extracted_text.append(text)

# Find all divs with class "hidemain"
divs = soup.find_all("div", class_="hidemain")

# For each div found, look for the a tag inside
# and extract the link text contained in this tag
for div in divs:
    a_tag = div.find("a")
    if a_tag:
        link = a_tag.get("href")
        extracted_text.append(link)

# Save the extracted text to a text file
with open("links.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in extracted_text:
        f.write(line + "\n")
```

I can't understand the problem of why it doesn't return the text I ask for

Comment: what does `print(len(tds))` show?

Comment: `tds = soup.find_all("td", style="word-wrap:break-word")` is missing the `;` after `break-word`

Comment: @Barmar `print(len(tds))` will show the number of td elements in the HTML code that have the `"word-wrap:break-word"` style attribute.

Comment: @Barmar after your correction I solved, look my answer

Comment: I know what it's supposed to do, I wanted to know what number you were getting.

Answer (score 0):

After @Barmar code edit i get this output

```
Death - Individual Thought Patterns (1993), Progressive Death Metal
Alfadog (1994), Black Metal
http://xxxxxxx.bb/1196198
http://yyyyyyyyyyyy.com/files/153576607/d-xxx_xxx_xxx-xxxxx-xxxxx.rar
```

To make the desired lines appear in the order they appear in the html file

```
Death - Individual Thought Patterns (1993), Progressive Death Metal
http://xxxxxxx.bb/1196198
http://yyyyyyyyyyyy.com/files/153576607/d-xxx_xxx_xxx-xxxxx-xxxxx.rar
Alfadog (1994), Black Metal
```

I modified the code to extract the links first and then the titles.

Specifically, I modified using two for loops, one to extract links and the other to extract song titles. Also, I used the extend function to add the extracted items to the extract_text list instead of using the append function.

This is the fixed code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Open the HTML file in read mode
with open("C:/temp/pagina.html", "r") as f:
    html = f.read()

# Create a Beautiful Soup object from HTML code
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Initialize a list to contain the extracted text
extracted_text = []

# Find all divs with class "hidemain"
divs = soup.find_all("div", class_="hidemain")

# For each div found, look for the a tag inside
# and extract the link text contained in this tag
for div in divs:
    a_tag = div.find("a")
    if a_tag:
        link = a_tag.get("href")
        extracted_text.extend([link])

# Find all td's with style "word-wrap:break-word"
tds = soup.find_all("td", style="word-wrap:break-word;")

# For each td found, look for the div tag and the b tag inside
# and extract the text contained in these tags
for td in tds:
    div_tag = td.find("div")
    b_tag = div_tag.find("b")
    if b_tag:
        text = b_tag.text
        # Also add the text after the b tag
        text += td.text[td.text.index(b_tag.text) + len(b_tag.text):]
        extracted_text.extend([text])

# Save the extracted text to a text file
with open("links.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in extracted_text:
        f.write(line + "\n")
```